# Unable to connect to a database using JDBC within Spark with Scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, jdbc, databricks

I’m trying to read data from JDBC in Spark Scala. Below is the code written in Databricks.

```
val df = spark
  .read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", <connection-string>)
  .option("dbtable", <table-name>)
  .option("user", <username>)
  .option("password", <password>)
  .option("ssl", True)
  .option("sslmode", "require")
 .load()
```

I’m getting the following error message:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to 10.6.8.86:3306 : PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Could someone please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is the extra parentheses before Spark a typo? It’s just a detail…

Comment: Its just a typo. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificate used by your host is not trusted by java.

Solution 1 (Easy, not recommended)

Disabled certificate checking and always trust the certificate provided by server.

Add `trustServerCertificate` property.

```
val df = (spark
  .read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", <connection-string>)
  .option("dbtable", <table-name>)
  .option("user", <username>)
  .option("password", <password>)
  .option("ssl", True)
  .option("trustServerCertificate", True)
  .option("sslmode", "require")
 .load()
```

Solution 2 (Difficult, Recommended)

Get the certificate and store it in the trusted store of your system.

Read more about it here

- https://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed/
- ["PKIX path building failed" and "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ)

Comment: Thank you  for the answer.

Comment: Could you show me how to "Disabled certificate checking and always trust the certificate provided by server."?